# trying to select first value from List using linq

Tags: c#

I'm trying to select first value from list based on selection of first dropdown
Using Linq".below i have attached the screen shot for further clarification on the issue.
C# code

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Escalation(FormCollection _frm)
        {
            ErpCode = Session["ErpCode"].ToString();
            List<IssueEL> _issue = new List<IssueEL>();
            IEnumerable<IssueEL> empdetail = new List<IssueEL>();
            try
            {
                if (_frm["Type"].ToString() == "BindIssue")
                {
                    ViewData["Dept"] = _frm["ddlDepartment"];
                    _issue = _dam.Issues.ToList();
                    _issue = (from n in _issue where n.DepartmentId == _frm["ddlDepartment"].ToString() select n).ToList();
                    ViewBag.IssueType = _issue.ToList();                    
                    empdetail = _dam.Issues.ToList();
                    empdetail = empdetail.GroupBy(x => new { x.Employee}).Select(x => x.First());
                    ViewBag.Employee = empdetail;
                    ViewData["Issue"] = "";
                    ViewData["Emp"] = "";
                }
                List<Department> _dep = _dam.Departments.ToList();
                ViewBag.Department = _dep.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _apm.GetException(ex, "GetFeeds", "EmployeeController");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

cs Html

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Escalation", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "IssueForm" }))
        {
            <div class="col-md-12 text">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    Department
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    @Html.DropDownList("ddlDepartment", new SelectList(ViewBag.Department, "DepartmentId", "DepartmentName", ViewData["Dept"]), "-- " +
             HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Department", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString() + " --", new { @class = "form-control"})
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    Issue Type
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    @Html.DropDownList("ddlIssue", new SelectList(ViewBag.IssueType, "IssueId", "IssueType", ViewData["Issue"]), "-- Select Issue --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    Employee
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    @Html.DropDownList("ddlEmploy", new SelectList(ViewBag.Employee, "EmployeeId", "Employee", ViewData["Empl"]), "-- " +
             HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Employ", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString() + " --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    Priority
                </div>
```

Details are provided in image[image]

Comment: Look at [FirstOrDefault()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` is the LINQ method, but any particular reason you can't just use `listName[0]`?

Comment: I' m trying this  empdetail = empdetail.GroupBy(x => new { x.Employee}).Select(x => x.First());  in above code   Could you suggest how to modify it as it provide all single value from different department

Answer (score 0):

use [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
ViewBag.Department = _dep.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant you do it this way?

```
string dep = _frm['ddlDepartment'].ToString();
Issue tmp=dbContext.Issues.where(x=>x.DepartmentId==dep).FirstOrDefault();
ViewBag.TMP = tmp;
```

Then in your view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EmployeeName,new SelectList(ViewBag.TMP,"EmployeeName", "EmployeeName"))
```

Comment: it should be dynamic

Comment: For demo purpose, I added it, you can replace `D012` with your own variable.

Comment: hi i'm trying to do same as for issue type actually i'm new to this and no idea how to do it.can u suggest   im trying as below _issue bind                                                            _issue = (from n in _issue where n.DepartmentId == _frm["ddlDepartment"].ToString() select n).ToList();                                                     second example for binding employee                                                                          empdetail = _dam.Issues.Where(x => x.DepartmentId == _frm["ddlDepartment"].ToString()).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: I mean how to fill selected value in Department Dropdown in place of'D012' in query                                                                                     Issue tmp=dbContext.Issues.where(x=>x.DepartmentId=='D012').FirstOrDefault();

Comment: You need to use some kind of  `model` or  `viewmodel` that can transport your data from html page to controller action. From that model you can easily access DepartmentId

Comment: I have attached cshtml part also please chek it and suggest how fill that selected value in department dropdown in the query you provided

Comment: I have use table master in escalation model  [Table("IssueMaster")]
    public class IssueEL
    {
        [Key]
        public int IssueId { get; set; }
        public string IssueType { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string Employee { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @anuj, I have updated my code with which, your department selectedvalue will be transfered to `FormCollection _frm` and then you can access it as I suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133955/discussion-between-anuj-and-hemal).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FirstOrDefault()` in LINQ. This will basically return the first value of the list or a default value if the list is empty

```
List<Department> _dep = _dam.Departments.ToList();
ViewBag.Department = _dep.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean here but here's a logical explanation that can be used for all of Linq.

Linq works with all `Enumerable`, `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerable<T>`, and `IQueryable<T>` object types...  If you have a reference to linq 'using System.Linq' then you can or should be able to query any of those object types such as arrays, lists, etc.

So, to get the first item of any of those types you simply put...

```
var first = someEnumeratedObject.First();
```

Now, if there is no first object then you will get an error. ONLY use `.First()` if you want to throw an error when nothing is there for first to return.

The most popular and probably best option is to use `FirstOrDefault()` which will return `default(T)` if that object doesn't exist.

```
var first = someEnumeratedObject.FirstOrDefault();
```

There is one catch that you often don't care about but should be aware of. When using `FirstOrDefault()` the compiled return type `default(T)` meaning if it's a non-nullable type you will get back the default value.  So be careful.

An example would be a list of integers. If your first value is 0 in then `FirstOrDefault()` will return 0... If your list is empty then your `FirstOrDefault()` will still return 0. Sometimes you need to decide which to choose carefully.

```
    var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    var list2 = new List<int>();
    Console.WriteLine(list.First()); //Prints 1
    //Console.WriteLine(list2.First());  <- Throws an error
    Console.WriteLine(list.FirstOrDefault()); //Prints 1
    Console.WriteLine(list2.FirstOrDefault()); //Prints 0

    Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this!!

```
var firstItemsInGroup = from b in empdetail
             group X by X.Employee into g select g.First();
```